# How do I make Sphinx autodoc build from outside the source directory?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I have the following project structure:

```
root
  my_source_dir
  README.md
```

Note `my_source_dir` is not the same name as Sphinx's expected `source`-named directory.

I wish to set up Sphinx so that the resulting structure is as follows:

```
root
  build
    [HTML here]
  documentation
    [RST files here]
  my_source_dir
  Makefile
  README.md
```

So I set up sphinx in the root dir:

```
sphinx-quickstart
Source root path: .
Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y
```

This creates:

```
root
  build
  source
    conf.py
    index.rst
  my_source_dir
  Makefile
  README.md
```

Now source is the wrong directory, but we can just move over the files:

```
root
  build
  my_source_dir
    conf.py
    index.rst
  Makefile
  README.md
```

I add autodoc to `conf.py`:

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))
extensions = ["sphinx.ext.autodoc", "sphinx.ext.napoleon"]
[REST OF FILE UNCHANGED]
```

I also update the source dir in the makefile:

```
SOURCEDIR = my_source_dir
```

Now I run autodoc:

```
sphinx-apidoc -o documentation my_source_dir/
```

This creates:

```
root
  build
  documentation
    [RST FILES]
  my_source_dir
    conf.py
    index.rst
  Makefile
  README.md
```

I finally run `make html` which gets me to my desired structure:

```
root
  build
    [HTML here]
  documentation
    [RST files here]
  my_source_dir
  Makefile
  README.md
```

But if I open the built docs, the files in `my_source_dir` have not been detected. My docs are completely empty!

If I repeat this whole process from within `my_source_dir`, i.e. treating it as the root directory, my docs build perfectly and detect all the code. However, this leaves the makefile, build and docs directories inside `my_source_dir` which I do not want!

How can I build with Sphinx from outside my source directory while still using autodoc?

Comment: Python files are in `my_source_dir`. There is a warning: `nonexisting document 'documentation/modules'. This led me to the solution, move the conf.py and index.rst files out to the root level, and build again.

Answer (score -1):

The error was in moving `conf.py` and `index.rst` to `my_source_dir`.

Place them in the root dir:

```
root
  build
  documentation
    [RST FILES]
  my_source_dir
  conf.py
  index.rst
  Makefile
  README.md
```

Then rerun:

```
sphinx-apidoc -o documentation my_source_dir/ && make html
```

Docs now detect the code.

Comment: This is not a good solution because documentation files will be included in your project's dist. `conf.py` and other documentation files should be in `documentation`. A better solution uses the `include` directive, where a file in `documentation/` includes `README.md` and any other document at the root of the project.